# Are you able to use Material UI to style a Shopify website?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, shopify, shopify-hydrogen

I am getting ready to build out a shopify storefront, but I have never done so before and have some questions. I like how easy it is to build a mobile and desktop view utilizing Material UI, I have found some articles online that seems to indicate people have done so in the past but I also seem to recall reading in their docs CSS frameworks like Bootstrap or Tailwind are what is supported on Shopify. In an ideal world I would like to be able to use Next.js / React with SASS and Material UI for styling, essentially just using shopify for their ecommerce solution and as a CMS. Alternatively if sticking with Hydrogen is the preferred solution would I be able to remove tailwind and still use MUI?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that Shopify is 100% HTML, JS and CSS. How you choose to approach your storefront is just a combination of that, in ways you are comfortable with. You get to choose everything in there, knowing you manage your data with Shopify.

It also depends on your skill. You can leverage the Hydrogen and get away with almost anything your skills can provide, or you can let Shopify do most of the work, leaving you to just tinker with CSS.

In all cases, you are free as a bird to pick your CSS. Shopify chains you to nothing.